# Contact company for job description enquiry or use cover letter to communicate intentions

Tags: job-search, job-description

I saw on a company website two job descriptions that intrigues me.

One seems for a role that is pretty generic, but list among the duties the field in which I am interested to. Another one is a position for exactly what I would love to do. Both are open to graduate as I am, but there is a caveat with the second one.

The position I'd really like require the experience with an API that I don't have, but I do have experience in a similar API that has the same concepts behind (namely I am talking of DirectX and OpenGL). On contrary, there's no specification for the more "general" one.

Ultimately my goal is to get the second position, should I:

1. Contact the company through the email they use for applications (looks like a general recruitment address) and, being clear I am eager to learn what I do not know, ask if it makes sense to apply for that role having similar experiences.
2. Mention clearly my current experiences and my will of learning what I don't have at the best of my capabilities, even on my spare off-the-clock time, on the covering letter.

For both option I am willing to say that I can cover the first (the more general one) role if found fit for it, but eventually I want to move to the second one as soon they think I can be suitable for it.

I would lean towards the option 2, but I am scared of being rejected by a parser of my CV.

Comment: Hi anon, and welcome to the site. At the moment, this question is a little bit too close to a "What job should I take?" question, which is likely to get it closed as being off topic. Is your question "How do I phrase my covering letter when there are two different positions with the same company I am interested in applying for?"? If so, maybe you could [edit] to make that a little clearer and make your question less likely to be closed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually my Question is not about what should I take, but "How should I communicate my interests giving my situation to the recruiter/company"

Answer (score 2):

You have a question that you'd like answered before you write an application. That's a great opportunity!

## Call them.

This serves 3 purposes.

1. You get an answer to your question. Not bad for a start.
2. You get to know a real life person. This way, you can direct your cover letter to a person, not to an unpersonal "dear sir or madam". Make sure you mention your call in the cover letter.
3. You are known. You are no longer one of the 100 black-on-white letters that *all* say "I'm a good programmer, hire me please". *You* are different. *You* are the one who called. You are the one who *cared!* That sets you apart from the other 99 who are still faceless entities on a piece of paper.

Comment: I would gladly do it, but unfortunately this advert is about a newly created subsidiary of a big company which HQ is in another country. Unfortunately there is no website or direct contact for this new sub-company other than the email to which direct the application.

Comment: If the entity exists (the subsidiary) then there must be some way to contact them - look harder. Even if you call the parent company and ask them "hi, I'm trying to get hold of your subsidiary in xyz-place, but having some difficulty locating their number"